MAUI .NET 8 iOS - Method not found: SkiaSharp.SKMatrix SkiaSharp.SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(single,single)
I have created a new MAUI .NET 8 project and migrated the Xamarin forms project code.
I am facing an exception as below when loading the SVG image,
Unhandled Exception:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: SkiaSharp.SKMatrix SkiaSharp.SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(single,single)
at SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg.LoadElements(IEnumerable`1 elements, SKCanvas canvas, SKPaint stroke, SKPaint fill)
at SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg.Load(XDocument xdoc)
at SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg.Load(XmlReader reader)
at SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg.Load(Stream stream)
at SKM_MOBILE.UI.Core.Utils.CommonUtils.GetSVG(String svgName, Boolean isEnergized, Boolean inService, String imagePath)
at SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.SKCanvasView.OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
at SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.SKCanvasView.SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.ISKCanvasView.OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
at SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Handlers.SKCanvasViewHandler.OnPaintSurface(Object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
at SkiaSharp.Views.iOS.SKCanvasView.OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
at SkiaSharp.Views.iOS.SKCanvasView.Draw(CGRect rect)
at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 args, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 58
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 94
at SKM_MOBILE.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/macmini3/Documents/MAUI/SKM_MOBILE/SKM_MOBILE/Platforms/iOS/Program.cs:line 13

This is my code,
svg.Load(stream); throws this exception.
using (var stream = GetImageStream(svgName.Replace(".PNG", ".svg").Replace(".png", ".svg"), imagePath))
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
        svg.Load(stream);
        SVGComponentImage[$"{key}"] = svg;
    }
}

How do I resolve this issue?

SkiaSharp is not the best in terms of avoiding breaking changes. In the current version there is no SKMatrix.MakeTranslation method, as it has been renamed to CreateTranslation at some point. For a few versions the old MakeTranslation existed as an obsolete method (the documentation still contains it), but then they completely removed it.
One of your projects (maybe the original one from Xamarin) still may reference an older version of the SkiaSharp package but if you reference a newer version of it in at least one project, the newer .dll will be used eventually. So make sure you use the same version everywhere (if you use Visual Studio, the Reconcile tab in the Manage NuGet References window may help).
If the old version is referenced indirectly by an older 3rd party package you use (maybe the SKM_MOBILE.UI.Core project references an older SkiaSharp.Extended package, referencing the old SkiaSharp version with MakeTranslation?), then you might want to either upgrade that package if there is a newer version of it, or you can try to downgrade the direct SkiaSharp package references in your projects.
Normally this kind of DLL hell would not happen if the newer SkiaSharp versions would be at least compile compatible with the previous ones. Instead of actually removing obsolete members, they should have just hide them from IntelliSense (eg. by EditorBrowsableAttribute). If the options above are not applicable for you (for example, two 3rd party packages reference different incompatible versions and none of them can be satisfied), then I recommend to file an issue in the SkiaSharp repo to restore the obsoleted members in the next release so every package that use old references can be happy again.
